# Maven Mojo: execute to "package" and get .jar

Tags: maven, mojo

i'm writing a maven-mojo for a custom integration-test. The problem is now, i need the jar-file in the mojo-execution. If i configure my project to run my custom-plugin on phase "package" and run `mvn package`, it works just fine, i can get the file with

```
@Component( role = MavenProject.class )
private MavenProject project;
//.... in execute:
project.getArtifact().getFile()
```

But if i run my goal myself `mvn mypluginname:mygoal` the getFile() just returns null. My mojo-class is annotated with `@Execute( phase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE )`, shouldn't this execute all lifecycles to "package", so the .jar is "ready to get"? Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: It would be interesting what so special for your integration tests? Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Well, integration-test is maybe the wrong word. What i'm trying to do is something like jetty:run does. My software/project is kinda like a addon, so i want to start the other software with my .jar as argument, so my other software loads it and can tell me, if my project is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force a direct invocation of the goal, use

> @requiresDirectInvocation: Flags this Mojo to be invoke directly.

to configure your Mojo to do so. Moreover I suggest to throw an **org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException**, if the jar file has not been packaged (the package phase of the default lifecycle has not been invoked) yet. Try to specify an error message, which is describes the case as best as possible. The user of your plugin must know, that he has to package the jar before he runs the plugin's goal.

**Edit:**
Regarding the problem with the artifact file. Please have a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.5.2/org/apache/maven/plugin/install/InstallMojo.java?av=f) of the Maven-Install-Plugin. Line 188-191 shows how to obtain the artifact file.

```java
// Inject Maven project
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
private MavenProject project;

// ...

// Mojo#excute() code
Artifact artifact = project.getArtifact();
File pomFile = project.getFile();

ArtifactMetadata metadata = new ProjectArtifactMetadata( artifact, pomFile );
artifact.addMetadata( metadata );

File file = artifact.getFile();
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help, but this won't give me the "File" of the packaged .jar. I can, of course, build the File-Object myself by taking the finalName and the buildpath(?), but i don't thing thats the "best" and cleanest way, there has to be a way to get it from maven.

Comment: Are you sure that the package phase has been invoked before? Regarding your problem, the maven-install-plugin does nothing else. It runs after the  package phase and tries to install the packaged artifact. Therefore it needs the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to inject the MavenProject is via `@Parameter` and no longer via `@Component`. See the [evaluation guide.](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html) and the [annotation guide](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html).

```java
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
private MavenProject mavenProject;
```

Apart from that if you MOJO is annotated with `@Execute` it means to fork the life cycle which only makes sense if you call the mojo during the lify-cycle. Apart from forking the life cycle is usually not a good idea. If you prerequisite having a jar already built just use the package life cycle as default binding.

Comment: Well, i would do that, binding the plugin to "package", the problem is, that it will then run the external software everytime i install or deploy. I really want to run this only, if i call my goal directly. How does i.e. jetty:run do this? jetty:run also requires compilation before it can run the server.

Comment: Take a look at @gclaussn Answer which is the missing part.